# Link recognition broken in question and in comment it works incorrectly

Tags: support, hyperlinks

I was just posting an answer on SO, and I have found this strange behavior.
I was inserting a link, which looks ugly, but HP and IBM tend to have such weird links:

```
https://h10078.www1.hp.com/cda/hpms/display/main/hpms_content.jsp?zn=bto&cp=1-11-126-17^8_4000_100__
```

I inserted the link into the dialog using the icon above the text input area. But the marked words which supposed to be the hyperlink are displayed as normal words, not as a hyperlink.

When I checked the source, the link I have inserted was not there, although when I edit the question it is there.

I tried also the following, but without success:

```
<http://foo.com>
[foo](http://foo.com)
<a href="http://foo.com">foo</a>
```

I thought that parsing this link is faulty in general, but when I just copied the link into the comment it is active. But the numbers at the end are not treated as a part of the link:

```
^8_4000_100__
```

Comment: This answer: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1766345/list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the [caret (`^`) is an unsafe character](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm) and needs to be encoded as `%5E`.

So this:

```
zn=bto&cp=1-11-126-17^8_4000_100__
```

Needs to be encoded as:

```
zn=bto&cp=1-11-126-17%5E8_4000_100__
```

Answer (score 2):

[As of recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60211/auto-escape-url-when-entering-with-hyperlink-button-ctrll/82263#82263), when entering a link via the button (or Ctrl-L), the characters will automatically be escaped.