# Auto escape URL when entering with hyperlink button (Ctrl+L)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, edits, editor

Whenever the following characters appear in an URL in a link of the form `[foo][1] … [1]: http://...`, the server won't parse it as URL:

- `^`, `{`, `}`, `\`

and the following won't work in preview:

- `$`, `^`, `*`, `[`, `]`, `{`, `}`, `\`, `'`, `"`

This causes great trouble when copying links from the URL bar. Browsers seldom escape every character, e.g. in Firefox `~!^*_-{}|[]\.` in a query string will not be escaped, while in Chrome ``~!$^*()_-{}|[]:;',./`won't be escaped. For example, [all 3 Wolfram Alpha links by this user](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1911/revisions) fails to appear because of`^`,`{`and`}`. Fixing these links are annoying.

Therefore, I propose that when one creates a link or image through the toolbar (Ctrl+L / Ctrl+G), **the system should be able to escape at least the above mentioned characters**.

Comment: A temporary workaround is to use something like [this](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/)

Comment: Minor detail: a trailing asterisk indeed does not work in preview, but not in the end result either, not even when using Ctrl-L or when explicitly using the angle brackets syntax like `<http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDA*>` (Maybe a clash with the Markdown for italic?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When entering a link via the dialog, we now make sure to encode "nasty" characters, so the resulting link definition is actually usable.

Comment: [yay!](http://instantrimshot.com/index.php?sound=yeehaw)

Comment: Am I right that the underscore is no longer escaped to be `%5F`? That is good, as Firefox treats an escaped underscore differently than Chrome, which might mess up when the server is not configured correctly. Like try `http://pear.php.net/package/XML%5FSerializer` in both browsers, and in Firefox note the URL [in the 404 message](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3SUBw.png). If indeed the underscore is no longer escaped *by design*, then I guess the ancient [Link with underscore does not work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16004/link-with-underscore) is actually `status-completed` by now! :-)