# Markdown hyperlink with dashes not rendered as a link - why not?

Tags: support, markdown, hyperlinks

I've answered a question on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775652/problem-performing-2-actions-using-one-link/3775722#3775722).  Embedded are two seemingly identical hyperlinks - but only one appears in markdown preview.  Same when the page is returned from the server.  The first was typed, the second pasted - after googling for the wikipedia page for 'Model-View-Controller'.  Both links can be seen in the source.

Browser is Safari on OS X.

What's going on there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the dashes; they are right (45) in the first link, and wrong (8211 = en-dash) in the second. Change the dashes. Did you copy them from the same place?

Comment: Thanks for that Mark - I googled for MVC, visited the wikipedia page, and pasted in the url to the popup box.  Then when it didn't work I typed it in.

Comment: @martin - indeed, wiki does have an en-dash version of the same page, but when I copy the URL in Chrome the url is correctly escaped to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93View%E2%80%93Controller

Comment: @martin often the plain-ascii equivalent also works in wikipedia urls

Comment: interesting, time to update my Chrome and give it a spin.  I was using Safari on OS X.  Firefox escapes as does Chrome.  I should have made the deductive leap from 'I see no differences' to 'the difference must be invisible'... Thanks again.

Comment: @Jeff - thanks - the ascii equivalent does indeed work here.  Seems like Safari is somewhat lacking when it comes to copy-paste of URLs from the address bar with chars that need to be escaped.

Answer (score 2):

[As of recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60211/auto-escape-url-when-entering-with-hyperlink-button-ctrll/82263#82263), when entering a link via the button (or Ctrl-L), the characters will automatically be escaped.