# Curly brackets in URLs

Tags: support, markdown, hyperlinks

Posting a bug report on Stack Apps, I tried to link to its API docs:

> http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/help/method?method=posts/{id}/comments

It was unsuccessful, and making the link explicit with `[http://url.com][1]` doesn't work either because the link doesn't show up. E.g., [*this is supposed to be a link*](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/help/method?method=posts/%7Bid%7D/comments).

Comment: Based on copying the Markdown for this question into [answer to: "Formatting Sandbox"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/386447/271271), the issue which is being asked about here is no longer seen in SE's backend conversion of Markdown to HTML (and also isn't seen in the normal in-page editor preview).

Comment: NOTE: DO NOT EDIT THIS QUESTION! If you edit this question, then the Markdown will be re-converted to HTML and the example of the issue will no longer appear. If you want to see what SE's backend currently does with the Markdown in this question, then you can look at [answer to: "Formatting Sandbox"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/386447/271271).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically encode illegal characters in URLs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/72625/282094)   https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370143/282094

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[RFC 1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738#page-3) states that certain characters are unsafe in URLs:

> Unsafe:
>
> Characters can be unsafe for a
> number of reasons. [...]  Other
> characters are unsafe because
> gateways and other transport agents
> are known to sometimes modify    such
> characters. These characters are **"{",
> "}"**, "|", "", "^", "~",    "[", "]",
> and "`".
>
> All unsafe characters must always
> be encoded within a URL. For
> example, the character "#" must be
> encoded within URLs even in  systems
> that do not normally deal with
> fragment or anchor    identifiers, so
> that if the URL is copied into another
> system that    does use them, it will
> not be necessary to change the URL
> encoding.

The `{` symbol should be replaced with `%7B` and `}` with `%7D`.

For example: http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/help/method?method=posts/%7Bid%7D/comments

Comment: I would aks why they're not encoded on [SO](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/help), but still that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: If the URL is "unsafe", then I'd rather the entire URL is left alone as plain text, rather than having a mixture of a URL and an unparsed extension.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like those links are working now, but they should not. Using the new API endpoint to demonstrate:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/comments/{ids}?site=stackoverflow
```

This is not a URI. As mentioned previously, curly braces are unsafe characters, and are not valid in URIs (see [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)). For the purposes of API documentation, and other similar uses, they should *not* be percent encoded, however, because they still aren't URIs - they don't identify a resource. When the embedded parameter expression is expanded, in this case by replacing it with a semicolon delimited list of ids, they do identify a resource. As such, it's a valid URI.

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/comments/1;2?site=stackoverflow

Using curly braces to indicate an embedded parameter in a URI-like descriptor - called a URI template - is defined by [RFC 6570](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570).

Answer (score -1):

RFC 1738 has been obsoleted by RFC 3986, and 3986 makes no mention of curly brackets.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986

Comment: In response to [waiwai933's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79057/curly-brackets-in-urls/79060#79060)? What is the conclusion? That they are safe? Or not invalid (that is, valid)? Or something else? Please respond by [editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/386446/edit) your answer, not here in comments.

Comment: I'd also note that this the issue described in the question is obsolete. SE's backend no longer has the issue for which the OP was asking for support.

Comment: That means that they are officially safe, just like the letter "a."