# (Auto) skip/limit the vote when there's no extra candidates?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support, election

I just voted in [the Engineering election](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/election/1), when I noticed that there are **the same number of candidates as there are positions**:

> [image: Pointless election?]

There is nothing in [the Election FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135360/theres-an-election-going-on-whats-happening-and-how-does-it-work) about this, but [this old, not so easy to find, question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78411/moderator-elections) shows that a similar election was manually terminated, years ago.

So, **should such elections be automatically skipped, manually terminated, or just allowed to continue** in obscurity?

---

1. Continuing the election does give some a chance to earn shiny new *Caucus* and *Constituent* badges.
2. Cutting the voting short means that the new moderators can get on the job that much quicker. (The election is being held because mods are needed *now*-ish, right?)
3. I suppose the 1st place winner could lord it over the 2nd place
   winner?
4. Skipping or terminating such elections frees up everybody's time for more productive Stack Exchange pursuits?

---

#### Feature-request:

I humbly request that such elections be automatically limited to 24 hours.
That gives alert site participants a chance to pick up a badge, and gets the moderators on the job that much quicker.

Comment: I’m out of town but I’ll wrap up the election tomorrow. I don’t trust myself to wrap up the election on my phone! Sorry for the confusion. (Third edit on this comment.)

Comment: Thanks, @JonEricson, for closing the election.  But since it was retroactively closed at the starting time, does that mean that our shiny new [*Constituent* badges](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/badges/81/constituent) will go away?

Comment: Not unless I take them away. Should I take them away? ;-)

Comment: @JonEricson, please don't take My Precious away.  How else can I show my coworkers that I'm more civic-minded than they are? (^_^)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We don't have any automation for this right now and today's a holiday in the US but  beta elections already have a rule for this - if the number of candidates == slots, the election ends early and the candidates will get appointed.

If you check out the Beta Election post for Engineering, [Announcing a Pro Tempore election](https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/560/15155), it actually has a caveat for this situation:

> - On September 3, if there are three or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll simply appoint the candidates.

The Election FAQ hasn't been updated to reflect beta site elections yet, largely because they're still very new and being tested out. In general, we have required that elections have at least one more candidate than seats or the election is ended and invalid.

We'll get the election ended soon and they'll get their diamonds as soon as someone who can do all of this is around.

Comment: Thanks. Ironically, I didn't get notified of that election before today (so didn't see that post). (Maybe because I didn't have enough rep?)

Answer (score 1):

Your election appears to be on a beta site.

The team has stated that if by the time the nomination period ends the number of nominees are less than or equal to the number of moderator positions, they will (within reason) simply make the nominees moderators.

On graduated sites, there's no written rule, though I've seen elections cancelled entirely if there are fewer nominees than positions.

Comment: Where did they state that?  I couldn't find anything except the 2 questions I linked.