# Provide an unambiguous description of how election votes are counted using the OpenSTV software

Tags: feature-request, election, documentation

[A moderator election just finished up on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/4). Eager to find out who won, right after the election closed I followed the given directions:

[image]

I opened the OpenSTV program, loaded the election data file, chose "Meek STV", and... hmm...

[image]

[image]

What is "ballot cleaning"? "Precision"? "Threshold"? I have no idea what any of these things do, and what appears to be [the only relevant meta.SO page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77541/161783) doesn't say which of the **336** combinations of options I should set.

Yes, the program has defaults - but are those defaults how the SE team computes the official results?

Yes, I bet these settings would rarely affect the outcome - but if an election ever occurs where they **do** matter, it puts the SE team in the awkward position of having to decide which options to use [when they are able to see how their decision is going to affect the outcome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_presidential_election_in_Florida,_2000#U.S._Supreme_Court_Proceedings).

Adding a completely unambiguous description of how election votes are being counted should be a simple fix that might prevent a big headache in the future.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We use the MeekSTV method and the default options.